# There are currently no logon servers available

Tags: fedora

we are using free-ipaserver(192.168.0.200) on fedora, clients are windows xp.
we are successfully added two xp clients(m01(192.168.0.60, m02(192.168.0.61) on test environment.
and also our server name is **ipaserver** & domain name is xyz.com , samba has been configured working fine.
problem is whenever we access from one xp machine another xp machine  we are getting this error, There are currently no logon servers available to service the logon request,
please give the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

1. make sure the computers in the same network, the same workgroup and **have created
   the same username**.
2. use net.exe to cache the credential